# Непрерывная интеграция и деплой php проекта

Tags: php, развертывание, непрерывная-интеграция

Только недавно я понял, что такое непрерывный деплой и интеграция. И теперь я это хочу. Но встал вопрос: что лучше всего выбрать для этого.
Задача такая:

1. Инструмент непрерывной интеграции реагирует на хук с гит репозитория после очередного пуша и врубает билд. Он должен подтянуть все композер пакеты, выполнить подготовительные команды и запустится. Далее он прогоняет по всем тестам, проверяет стиль кода и т.п.
2. В случае **успешного** билда кидается запрос (предположим, POST) на другой (или тот же) сервер, на котором стоит деплоер.
3. Деплоер должен уметь как минимум работать с композером и запускать консольные команды.
4. Ситуация такая, что в папке с релизом могут быть необходимые файлы, которые тянутся от релиза к релизу. Например, изображения к постам. И они должны сохраниться.

Нашел [вот это](https://www.phptesting.org/) и оно кажется неплохим для непрерывной интеграции. 
Хочу инструменты, которые могут

1. Работать с несколькими проектами
2. Можно все тонко настроить
3. Настраиваться через веб интерфейс (не обязательно, но очень желательно, особенно для непрерывной интеграции)
4. Поддержка конфигурационного файла для каждого проекта (как в travis `.travis.yml`)
5. Опять же, чем меньше требования, тем лучше. Если инструмент может работать на чистом PHP и MySQL и использованием shell, это большой плюс.

Comment: https://jenkins.io/index.html Можете попробовать.

Comment: @Moonvvell слышал, видел, но не пробовал. Смущает, что он работает на яве. Мне мы что-нибудь специализированное для моей задачи. Не хочется убивать день на танцы с бубном.

Comment: Да ну? Неужели нету людей, которые используют эту связку? Всяко же удобнее делать все автоматически, чем ручками погонять все тексты, а потом по ftp заливать файлы на хост.

Answer (score 2):

[TeamCity](https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) отлично решает все эти задачи.

Вы создаете билд и прикрепляете к нему систему контроля версий (TeamCity может сам делать чекаут либо можно повесить хук). Далее вы создаете Buils Steps. В моём случае это полная очистка базы данных, миграции и инит проекта. Далее composer install и запуск `sh` скрипта который запускает тесты. `sh` скрипт является частью проекта.

У меня следующая структура билдов (Unit - Integration - Functional - Acceptance). Билдится каждый коммит. Каждый следующий билд выполняется если предыдущий прошел все тесты. Незачем запускать функциональные тесты если провалились юнит-тесты.

Каждый билд в результате на выходе может иметь отчеты и [артефакты](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Build+Artifact) (результат билда в виде файлов).

Для деплоя есть специальный плагин [Deployer](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/Deployer+plugin), но в принципе деплой можно настроить и с помощью `sh` скрипта. В моем случае я не деплоюсь копируя артефакты, а на проде скрипт делает `composer install`, и т.д. по стандартной схеме как если бы я всё делал ручками.

Зацените ещё [Dlm Automation Suite](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dlm/dlm-automation-suite/) от Red Gate. Крутейшая штука.

Хороший [интро в тимсити](http://courses.osherove.com/courses/beautifulbuilds) можно получить у Roe Osherove.

Comment: Еще пока ничего посмотреть не успел, но ставлю плюс за развернутый и красивый ответ. Позже все исследую и поставлю галочку, если это то, что мне нужно)

Comment: @vtvz_ru будут вопросы - пишите :)

Comment: Просмотрел на "крутейшую штуку".. Дорого. Тимсити выглядит интересно, но этот инструмент более универсальный, чем специфичный для php. Полагаю, некоторые вещи придется допиливать самому

Comment: @vtvz_ru лично мне после тимсити ни на какие другие CI-системы смотреть больше не хочется :) Связка yii2 + codeception встала идеально.

Comment: Я попробую и отпишусь сюда. Спасибо большое)

Comment: @vtvz_ru одна из киллфич - вы можете получать уведомления о прохождении билдов прямо в PHPStorm или в виде всплывающего уведомления.

Comment: это да, звучит интересно. Это какой-то плагин или встроенная фича?

Comment: @vtvz_ru официальный плагин